# Why is a span tag adding a big space before its contents in a p tag?

Tags: html, css

I've never had this happen before and I can't figure it out.  I'm putting a span tag in the middle of a p tag, and there's just a big space in the paragraph right before the contents of the span tag.  Can anyone tell me what stupid mistake I've made here?

[image: Problem]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Validate Course</title>
        <style>
            #validate {height: 800px; width: 50%; margin: auto; background: rgb(255, 140, 159); border-radius: 10px; border-left: 5px solid rgb(255, 126, 121);border-bottom:5px solid rgb(255, 126, 121)}
            #validate * {margin-left: 30px;}
            #course {padding: 4px;}
            #output {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="validate">
            <br />
            <h1 id="title">Validate Course</h1>
            <p>Enter Course Information: <input id="course" type="text" name="course" placeholder="AAA.111#2222_aa-1234" /></p>
            <p>Input is in <span id="output">incorrect</span> format.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change or delete this section.

```
#validate * {margin-left: 30px;}
```

Comment: My god I'm so stupid.  It's always these things that I just can't figure out.  I'm sorry for wasting your time :(  Thank you so much.